# Jenkins Timer Build fails for https svn url

Tags: svn, jenkins

My Jenkins scheduled builds are failing for https SVN url with error:

ERROR: Processing failed due to a bug in the code. Please report this to jenkinsci-users@googlegroups.com
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The date must not be null

Manually triggered builds works fine and also, this error is not coming when using http SVN url for checkout.

I am using Jenkins 1.467 version.

Comment: Did you try to report this to jenkinsci-users@googlegroups.com?

Comment: I tried mailing them but the mail was not delivered throwing error related to don't have permission